# Javascript - When a button is clicked the CSS property toggle after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I am working on a simple Play and Pause button code with Javascript. The script is toggling the CSS property; however, after a delay. At the moment, the toggle happens on second click. Not sure what the issue is.

```js
   $(document).click(function () {
      $("#startClock").click(function () {
          $("#startClock").css("display", "none");
          $("#stopClock").css("display", "block");
      });
      $("#stopClock").click(function () {
          $("#stopClock").css("display", "none");
          $("#startClock").css("display", "block");
      });
});
```

```css
#stopClock {
  display: none; 
}

#startClock {
  display: block;   
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>
<button id=startClock >Start</button>
<button id=stopClock >Pause</button> <br/>
```

Comment: change document.click to document.ready

Comment: You all are awesome.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$(document).click` go for `$(document).ready`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#startClock").click(function () {
         $("#startClock").css("display", "none");
         $("#stopClock").css("display", "block");
     });
     $("#stopClock").click(function () {
         $("#stopClock").css("display", "none");
         $("#startClock").css("display", "block");
     });
 });
```

```css
#stopClock {
  display: none; 
}

#startClock {
  display: block;   
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>
<button id=startClock >Start</button>
<button id=stopClock >Pause</button> <br/>
```

It was happening because on first `click` which was getting listen by `document`; the `click` event handler were getting attached to your `button`. Hence needed 2 clicks for the CSS animation.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#startClock").click(function() {
    $("#startClock").css("display", "none");
                                $("#stopClock").css("display", "block");
   });
   $("#stopClock").click(function() {
    $("#stopClock").css("display", "none");
                                $("#startClock").css("display", "block");
   });
  });
```

```css
#stopClock {
  display: none; 
}

#startClock {
  display: block;   
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>
<button id=startClock >Start</button>
<button id=stopClock >Pause</button> <br/>
```

Because at first you first time clicked it twice cause of click inside of click event. You clicked document and after clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

what if you change

```
$(document).click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

I can't see the context but it looks like you have two nested click listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you have wrapped code inside `$(document).click` It should be `$(document).ready()`

#### Sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#startClock").click(function() {
    $("#startClock").css("display", "none");
    $("#stopClock").css("display", "block");
  });
  $("#stopClock").click(function() {
    $("#stopClock").css("display", "none");
    $("#startClock").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
#stopClock {
  display: none;
}
#startClock {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>
<button id=startClock>Start</button>
<button id=stopClock>Pause</button>
<br/>
```

You should avoid using style attribute. Rather you should use `class`. If you switch to `class` approach, you can use, `toggleClass` or `addClass/removeClass` functions to update visibility.

#### Sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#startClock, #stopClock").click(function() {
    $("#startClock").toggleClass("hide");
    $("#stopClock").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>
<button id="startClock">Start</button>
<button id="stopClock" class="hide">Pause</button>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

Using `preventDefault` you can do it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startClock").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#startClock").css("display", "none");
        $("#stopClock").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#stopClock").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#stopClock").css("display", "none");
        $("#startClock").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Comment: I think in this example is preventDefault not necessary, but i agree thats this is a good pattern to use it if sometimes it will be used inside of form or binded on anchor.